# First line of awk output isn't what I expect

Tags: awk

I am trying to figure out why a part of a file name disappears.

In my case, I have created three files

```
$ ls
some-part-of-file.1  some-part-of-file.2  some-part-of-file.3
```

and when I use awk with `FS = "-"`, one of them is blank.

```
$ ( echo some-part-of-file.1 ; echo some-part-of-file.2 ; echo some-part-of-file.3 ) | awk '{ FS = "-" ; print $0 " " $2}'
some-part-of-file.1
some-part-of-file.2 part
some-part-of-file.3 part
```

Why does `some-part-of-file.1` `$2` not print `part` like the others?

Answer (score 11):

You get blank output for the first record, because that was already read and parsed when you set `FS`.

You must set the field separator *before* reading and parsing the input record. So either

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = "-" }{print $2}'
```

or

```
awk -F'-' '{print $2}'
```

Alternatively you can force `awk` to re-parse the current record after you set `FS`:

```
awk '{FS = "-"; $0 = $0; print $2}'
```

Regarding your pipeline, `grep` is not needed, `awk` can do that part too:

```
ls | awk -F'-' '/some-part-of-file/{print $2}'
```

Comment: See [the gawk documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Splitting-Summary.html#index-field-separators_002c-POSIX-and-609) and [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_01) for details